# change color after textedit event

Tags: event-handling, qt4, pyqt

what I try to achieve is, if a user is editing a specific field in my form (designed with QT Designer) the background color should turn into e.g. into red. Programmatically I can do it for one field, however, I have a lot of QLineEdits and QComboBoxes. Is there a possibility to do that for a selected number of elements all at once? Can this also be done with QT Designer only?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: Which event should trigger the coloring?
And can you provide a description of your UI, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect the signal *textChanged* of your lineEdit control to a slot. Then make that slot change the control stylesheet as you need.

Example:

```
yourControl.textChanged.connect(onEdit_slot)
```

then define the slot like

```
def onEdit_slot():
    sender().setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 254, 134, 150);")
```

PS: remember that stylesheet will remain the same until you change it, so after editing and losing focus your control will keep the red background. To change it back just connect the control's *editingFinished* signal to another slot and reset the stylesheet

Example:

```
yourControl.editingFinished.connect(onFinishedEditing_slot)
```

then define the slot like:

```
def onFinishedEditing_slot():
    sender().setStyleSheet("")
```